# Sometimes i get No changes detected when i try to do makemigrations

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

so my problem is that sometimes when I try to do makemigrations it gives me `No changes detected` error while I did some changes to my tables . 
I also tried `py manage.py makemigrations ( name of my app )` at first it acts like everything is ok and successful but then when you want to display the tables you edited in models.py it raise error which the new row doesnt exist. anyway i also tried to used `python manage.py migrate --fake`

Please give me some suggestion what to do !

Answer (score 0):

1- make sure your app in INSTALLED_APP

2- Make sure that you have not set a variable named app_lable in your meta model class, and if you have set it, you have set it correctly.

3- This problem may occur when you change the model a lot and make migrations for it

4- If there is still a problem, you should delete the database and re migrate it

Comment: reason number 3 looks reasonable for me because my projects is under development and im improving it so i change the db and model few times a week